# Device for multiple output to home theater system

Tags: pc, audio, speakers, audio-adapters

I have a home theater system, A PC, and a PS4. Every time I switch between using the PC and the PS4, I have to unplug the 3.5mm input for the speaker between the PS4 and the PC. This is frustrating since I have to go to the backside of the PS4 and PC all the time.

Now, I know I can buy an extension for the respective devices but I would have to manually swap each one.

Is there a device of some sort which will take two inputs, and based on a switch state, give the output to the speaker?

Answer (score 1):

The way I've solved this problem in the past is with the PC's line-in jack.  While it requires the PC to have power to output sound, it allows you to chain the output.  You may need to go into the sound device manager for your PC's operating system and toggle the Line-In jack to get this to work, but you should only have to do that once.  Some computers combine their microphone jack with line-in, but most have a separate input jack.

This is a problem, however, if you are using sound from both at once.  If your computer is also making sounds, you may need to mute applications on the PC or you will hear both at once.

An alternative is a switching box, but most that have wireless control are HDMI-only.  HDMI carries audio, so if you can switch to that interface for these devices and have multiple ports on your home theatre receiver or TV, that might be the better option altogether.

Comment: This means, I will have to turn on the PC all the time , even if  I have to use just the PS4 Right? , I think you are saying that use the PC as a mediator.

Comment: Yes.  It's not harmful to the PC, however, and if it's just an average home PC, it won't up your power bill noticeably either.